# First time app building

Tags: cordova, extjs, dreamweaver, sencha-architect

So my question is basically what is the best route to take for a webdesigner to build a native app for a website. I'd like to take the HTML5/jQuery route rather than the java/Objective C route.

The two things I have found are PhoneGap and Sencha Architect. Would one of these be my best course of action?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sencha Architect is paid IDE and phonegap is an open source framework. Its two different entities with different capabilities. to start learning or to start with I would suggest to take the phonegap approach. it has good dev support and hell lot of plugins to extend your app capabilities. Wider varieties of devices and its no extra learning other than phonegap's JS libraries.

You can couple Jquery mobile or zeptoJS for Better UI and data manipulations.

Comment: I agree with this, the current frameworks out there jQuery Mobile, jQTouch and Sencha are good.. but if you really want control and to not have to deal with bulky frameworks use jQuery or Zepto.